# MVC5 MEF Modul Routing custom area

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, mef

### Intro

I have a web application **Application** using MVC5. This application loads modules via [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/). I have a controller named `SysInfoController` inside my module **Plugin**.

The `SysInfoController` works perfectly fine and can be reached via

```
http://localhost/sysinfo/index
```

### Desired behaviour

I want to reach controllers inside my **Plugin** routed at a prefix

```
http://localhost/plugin/sysinfo/index
```

### My Question

How can I achieve the desired behavior without using *Areas*?

### Additional Information

- The UrlHelper returns `http://localhost/plugin/sysinfo/index` when using `Url.Action("Index", "SysInfo")` inside a view.

### Sources

My source code does create the desired behaviour.

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "plugin",
    url: "plugin/{controller}/{action}"
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
  );
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : KpmCfsHttpApplication
{
  protected void Application_Start()
  {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    RegisterModules(); // register MEF modules

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry I updated my text.